# How to get to the beginning of activity with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Need to pick another random track after stopping the previous one by clicking "stop" button

I'm playing a random track by clicking "play" button, stop it by clicking "stop" and then i need to randomize again, in other words, to pick another track.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button play36 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threesix);
    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    String[] listOfFiles = new String[0];
    try {
        listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");
        final List<String> musicOnlyList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (getExtension(listOfFiles[i]).equals("mp3"))
                musicOnlyList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
        }

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        play36.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int itemIndex = new Random().nextInt(musicOnlyList.size());
                String file = musicOnlyList.get(itemIndex);
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
                try {
                    afd = getAssets().openFd(file);
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();

            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this case i get the same track everytime i start and stop player, but need to randomize everytime by clicking "play" button

Comment: Code updated, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a new random number inside the listener of `play36`:

```
Button play36 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.threesix);
Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);

String[] listOfFiles = new String[0];
try {
    listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");
    final List<String> musicOnlyList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        if (getExtension(listOfFiles[i]).equals("mp3"))
            musicOnlyList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
    }

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    play36.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int itemIndex = new Random().nextInt(musicOnlyList.size());
            String file = musicOnlyList.get(itemIndex);
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
            try {
                afd = getAssets().openFd(file);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: for some reason app terminated: "play" -> "stop" -> "play" and terminated

Comment: You have to debug to find the line that causes the problem

Comment: Illegal State Exception, smth in states consequence

Comment: You know what, it was really easy, i just added `mediaplayer.reset` in `stop` button and before `mediaplayer.setDataSource` in `play36` button, but anyway thanks a bunch for your idea, it works!

Comment: @Huge_Noob your question did not mention problems on the stop button, but was about *pick another random track*. My answer was focused on this.

Comment: Well, my mistake mb, but ty a lot anyway!

Comment: No worries, if the problem is solved everything's fine.